# Jolt - Rename object name, array name and specific keys

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to convert the input JSON

```
{
  "Main header": {
    "line1": [
      {
        "model": "Cooper",
        "year": 2018,
        "type": "Hatchback",
        "motorization": "Electric",
        "colour": "Midnight Black",
        "stageID": "MGOP94810482042"
      }
    ],
    "line2": [
      {
        "model": "Cooper",
        "year": 2018,
        "type": "Hatchback",
        "motorization": "Diesel",
        "colour": "Silver",
        "stageID": "MGOP9183740194"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to output

```
{
  "My header": {
    "This is line 1": [
      {
        "Car Model": "Cooper",
        "Car Year": 2018,
        "type": "Hatchback",
        "motorization": "Electric",
        "colour": "Midnight Black",
        "stageID": "MGOP94810482042"
      }
    ],
    "This is line 2": [
      {
        "model": "Cooper",
        "year": 2018,
        "type": "Hatchback",
        "motorization": "Diesel",
        "colour": "Silver",
        "stageID": "MGOP9183740194"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can perform this in multiple different steps.

1. Rename line1 and line 2 headers

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Main header": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&"
        },
        "line1": {
          "@": "Line 1 header"
        },
        "line2": {
          "@": "Line 2 header"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```

2. Rename specific keys in a array

```
 [
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "Main header": {
         "line1": {
           "*": {
             "model": "Main header.line1.[&1].Car Model",
             "year": "Main header.line1.[&1].Car Year"
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
 ]
```

I am trying to create a combined jolt transform spec that can perform this conversion. I tried creating a couple of merged versions and one or the other doesn't seem to work. Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I managed to club the two operations and arrived at the below spec

```
 //Rename nested keys in array
 [
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "Main header": {
         "line1": {
           "*": {
             "model": "My Header.This is line 1.[&1].Car Model",
             "year": "My Header.This is line 1.[&1].Car Year",
             "@": "My Header.This is line 1.[&]"
           }
         },
         "line2": {
           "*": {
             "model": "My Header.This is line 2.[&1].Car Model",
             "year": "My Header.This is line 2.[&1].Car Year",
             "@": "My Header.This is line 2.[&]"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ]
```

But when I run this spec, there are two new keys (the ones I renamed) and all the existing keys are also present in the output. Is there a way I can remove the keys that I have renamed?

My latest output

```
{
  "My Header" : {
    "This is line 1" : [ {
      "model" : "Cooper",
      "year" : 2018,
      "type" : "Hatchback",
      "motorization" : "Electric",
      "colour" : "Midnight Black",
      "stageID" : "MGOP94810482042",
      "Car Model" : "Cooper",
      "Car Year" : 2018
    } ],
    "This is line 2" : [ {
      "model" : "Cooper",
      "year" : 2018,
      "type" : "Hatchback",
      "motorization" : "Diesel",
      "colour" : "Silver",
      "stageID" : "MGOP9183740194",
      "Car Model" : "Cooper",
      "Car Year" : 2018
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1**

Using remove operation

Append the spec at the end, removes the elements mentioned

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "model": "",
            "year": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Suggestion 2**

Shifting the each values instead of using @

```
"type": "My Header.This is line 1.[&1].type",
"motorization": "My Header.This is line 1.[&1].motorization",
"colour": "My Header.This is line 1.[&1].colour",
"stageID": "My Header.This is line 1.[&1].stageID"
```

Comment: Great. This works. However, is there a way I can shift all but two updated keys without using the remove operation?

Comment: Then you can go for Suggestion 2, Specifying the node names in the shift spec instead of @

Comment: This was just a sample JSON having similar structure to that of mine. There are 100's of keys my actual file and they are dynamic, so I cannot hard code each of them. The case was to convert only specific ones and retain the rest as-is.

Comment: Then. its better to prefer remove operation.